# Why rollup can't resolve the .d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs

I have a `.d.ts` file and `import` the `exports` in a `.ts` file, when i use `tsc` to compile the `.ts` file, it generates the `js` file successfully.

But when i use rollup(plugins with `rollup-plugin-typescript2` & `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` & `rollup-plugin-commonjs`), it reports can not resolve the import.

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before adding it or why do you think `rollup` is correct (_"The ROLLUP operator is useful in generating reports that contain subtotals and totals. The ROLLUP operator generates a result set that is similar to the result sets generated by the CUBE operator"_) ?